# Can't get MongoDB extention for PHP workign with new WAMP 2.5

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I just updated from WAMP 2.2e (Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13, MySQL 5.5.24) to WAMP 2.5 (Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12, MySQL 5.6.17). I was using the mongo driver 1.5.0RC2 with WAMP2.2e, with no problem.

With the update, I went to grab the latest Mongo driver, grabbing 1.5.4. The problem is no matter which of the 4 drivers for PHP 5.5 I put into my ext folder, none of them work. They all give me a small warning icon in the WAMP PHP extension menu and won't turn on, and if I add it to php.ini and restart Apache, it doesn't show up in phpinfo().

I have no idea why its not working or how to diagnose what's wrong.

EDIT: Previously, I was getting the drivers from https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html. I just went to http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.4/windows and downloaded the driver from there; this time, WAMP doesn't give me a warning icon, but PHPinfo still doesn't show me Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. In my case, i just set mongodb bin"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin" path in environment variable then restart the wamp and now everything is working fine with 1.5.5

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue was the latest driver. I was trying to use 1.5.4, kept saying 'The specified module could not be found'. I went down to 1.5.1 and it worked. I found posts suggesting older versions that did work for people, so I figured I can try downgrading. I had already tried 1.5.3 with no avail, so I kept going. 1.5.2 also failed, but 1.5.1 ended up working.